# What is BodyParsers.Default and how to pass it to a function

Tags: playframework-2.6, silhouette

I want to create instance of the following class defined at http://api.play.silhouette.rocks/5.0.0/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/api/actions/DefaultSecuredAction.html

```
new DefaultSecuredAction(requestHandler: SecuredRequestHandler, bodyParser: Default)
```

I cannot find out how to pass `bodyParser` of type `Default`. I am using compile time injection, thus I cannot use `@Inject()`.

The `bodyParser` is of type `play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.Default`.

So far, I have written following code

```
val securedAction = new DefaultSecuredAction(new DefaultSecuredRequestHandler(new DefaultSecuredErrorHandler(messagesApi)),/*???*/ )
```

The `Default` seem to be defined here - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$

But when I tried to use it, I got the following error